# glsl fragment shader work diffrently on different devices

Tags: android, libgdx, glsl, opengl-es2

i'm making a 2d android game where i have a mechanics that allow the player to move the camera away from the main character, and to not allow him to explore the hole world, a have create a Fog shader, know the shader works very well on the emulator, and in the desktop application from libgdx, but once i run it on real devices it give me a defferent output, in Xperia SP the for never get heigher and make every thing visible, and in a Galaxy S3 the Fog act like a Circle and make every thing invisible.
my question is : are shader work differently from gpu to one other.

Comment: You should post the shader source.

Comment: This strongly depends on the GPU vendor, who normally develops the driver as well. I also recognize that on different hardware the shader behaves differently; caused by some buggy implementation or quite more often by a buggy shader from myself. The question is: do you use features in your shader correctly? If yes: are their any known issues on the target hardware and drivers? If yes: which workaround do you can use?

Comment: You should also check for OpenGL errors if you're not already doing so.